# Jersey resources not found after deploying war to remote server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jersey

My app is working well on my local Glassfish4 server but jersey resources are not found when I uplaod the war to a remote glassfish4 server.
The resource path is 404 !

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved . Ok the remote Glassfish was v3 Prelude and, this one does not have Jersey libraries bundled.